# “docker build” requires exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I know there are several posts like this but nothing has worked so far, I have a Dockerfile inside a folder and I have tried the following commands:

`docker build <full/path> --label test1="test2" --tag myImage`

`docker build --file <full/path>/Dockerfile --label test1="test2" --tag myImage`

`docker build Dockerfile --label test1="test2" --tag myImage <full/path>`

`docker build --label test1="test2" --tag myImage --file <full/path>/Dockerfile`

`docker build Dockerfile --label test1="test2" --tag myImage .`

But I always get this error `docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.`

Strangely enough this only happens with an specific Dockerfile, I have another one in a similar folder structure and that one works fine:

```
/folder1
    /folder2
        Dockerfile   // This one works
        more files...
    /folder3
        Dockerfile   // This one fails
        more files...
```

Notice that I'm not running the commands from that same folders so I have to use absolute paths (since I'm running the commands from Java API) but it is still strange that one Docker file works and the other one fails since the folder structure is the same.

Comment: If you're trying to specify an alternate Dockerfile, you need a `-f` option – `docker build -f folder3/Dockerfile folder1`.

Comment: sorry, I have tried that too, I just updated the question

Comment: You are missing the part of giving the context in some of your commands. Can you try this command in your root folder: `docker build . -f folder1/folder3/Dockerfile --label test1="test2" -t myImage`

Answer (score 0):

So what I know is that optional arguments have to be BEFORE the only argument.

The only argument is your dockerfile / your path to the lockerfile.

```
docker build --label "test1=test2" --tag "myImage" .
```

Comment: I have tried that too: `docker build --label test1="test2" --tag img1 <full/path/to/dockerfile1>` This one works, and the next one fails:
`docker build --label test1="test2" --tag img2 <full/path/to/dockerfile2>`, from what I can see those two commands are exactly the same, so I don't know one if them is failing

Comment: Please be aware of the " in my version. The Label and the tag property are have "test1=test2" instead of test1="test2"

Comment: I will try that, thanks, but that doesn't explain why one of the commands works and the other one fails